# strange DOM insertion of is="undefined"

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

I am potentially casting responsibility onto the wrong areas but I noticed some odd layouts on my simple Ember app and when looking at the DOM through Chrome's debugger I'm noticing that each element has `is="undefined"` in it. Huh? Is this ember/htmlbars related? If not, does anyone have any pointers where else to look?

> note: I am using ember-cli 0.2.0 with ember 1.10; I also use Bootstrap's SASS library

p.s. here's an image snapshot of what I'm seeing:

[image]

---

```
<!-- application.hbs -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Overlock+SC|Nixie+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <h2 id="title" class="logo">Company Name</h2>
    <div class="tagline">tagline</div>  
</div>
<div class="top-menu">
    <div class="menu">
        <div {{bind-attr class=":choice isHome:selected"}} {{action 'navigator' 'index'}}>Home</div>
        <div {{bind-attr class=":choice isProducts:selected"}} {{action 'navigator' 'products'}}>Products</div>
        <div {{bind-attr class=":choice isPricing:selected"}} {{action 'navigator' 'pricing'}}>Pricing</div>
        <div {{bind-attr class=":choice isSignup:selected"}} {{action 'navigator' 'sign-up'}}>Sign Up</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    {{outlet}}  
</div>
```

Comment: and your code for this view/component

Comment: i added the `application.hbs` as all pages have this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Please read it on github page [here](https://github.com/unionups/ember-cli-bootstrap-sass)

`ember-cli-bootstrap-sass` is not compatible with anything above `Ember 1.8`. Because they require the `handlebar v1`.

I think this issue is because of incompatible versions.

There is an open issue [here](https://github.com/unionups/ember-cli-bootstrap-sass/issues/13) about same sort of problem.

Comment: Most of the incompatibilities for ember-cli-bootstrap-sass stemmed from the ember components it was shipping not bootstrap itself. That's why I created ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy which only brings in bootstrap.

Comment: Just to completely eliminate this as a possible cause though I did remove all bootstrap references and the same message continues to appear.

Comment: can you create a JS bin